# The best way to read SQL Query using .NET and Oracle

Tags: .net, oracle, stored-procedures

How can I get the result of a SQL query calculation?

Say, there are two cases"

```
CASE 1
 RETURN "Process ok"
CASE 2
 RETURN "Process failed"
```

This will be returned from the stored procedure.

Which is the best way to read this on .net, C# (Windows Forms)?

Comment: what did you try? show how you invoke the query from your C# please

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.71).aspx, this is a generic answer to a more then generic question

Comment: what about using a DataReader and reading returned string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's up to you to use `DataReader` if you think you can get multiple records, or an `ExecuteScalar` if you only get a single value, no records and no multiple columns, simply a string or an int...

here how to call a stored procedure and get a reader then read its first column:

```
using(var  conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=oracledb;User Id=UserID;Password=Password;"))
{
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "storedProcedurename";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(...);

    conn.Open();
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(dr.Read())
    {
        var yourResult = dr[0].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you are invoking a stored procedure or if you are trying to get a record set back.

As for stored procedures it can either assign values to `out` or `inout` parameters or generate a record set. For the former you need to specify the parameter kind using the [Direction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparameter.direction.aspx) property. As for the latter, everything works as a normal query except that you need to set `command.CommandType` to [CommandType.StoredProcedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype.aspx).

A typical SQL query looks like:

```
using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT something FROM YourTable";
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader["something"]);
        }
    }

}
```

As for the database connection I do recommend that you use `DbProviderFactory` to generate it to get as generic code as possible: http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/10/08/CreatingDataAccessLayerUsingDbProviderFactoriesDbProviderFactory.aspx